# How to get the code coverage for unit tests in hybris to sonarqube using jacoco

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco, sap-commerce-cloud

How can the unit test results of a hybris project be captured to jacoco.exec and published to sonarqube

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the code coverage details into jacoco.exec, we can use the following steps
1. Create a new xml file(jacoco.xml) which will be used as the build file by ant.(new file created since, we do not want to tamper the build.xml of the hybris platform)
2. Add the below components to the newly created jacoco.xml

```
  <project name="jacoco_rpt_pim" xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">
      <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath path="<path>/jacocoant.jar"/>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="jacocoalltests" description="runs allstests with jacoco attached">

        <jacoco:agent property="agentvmparam"
                      append="true"
                      output="file"
                      destfile="jacoco.exec"
                />

        <property name="testclasses.extensions" value="agcobackoffice"/>
        <ant dir="<PLATFORM_HOME>" target="unittests" inheritrefs="false">
            <property name="standalone.javaoptions" value="${agentvmparam}"/>
        </ant>
    </target>
  </project>
```

3. Now invoke the jacocoalltests target which will invoke the unittests to get the code coverage report.
4. Additionally, providing the path of the report to sonar, would help get the codecoverage in sonarqube.

Comment: Hi, where to put jacoco.xml? /cutomize/ext-accelerator/acceleratorservices/resources/acceleratorservices/ant ?

Comment: @Valleri - this is a custom created file and can be placed at any location. While executing the ant command, you can use -f option to specify the location of this file

Comment: Hi Aromal, How can I provide path of the report to sonar to get the coverage in sonarqube?